# Why is redirecting to google giving a strange result?

Tags: php

My code which doesn't involve any database or session gives perfect results

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
if(isset($_GET["engine"]))
{
if($_GET["engine"]=="google")
header("Location:http://www.google.com/search?q=".$_GET["q"]);
elseif($_GET["engine"]=="yahoo")
header("Location:http://search.yahoo.com/search?q=".$_GET["q"]);
if($_GET["engine"]=="bing")
header("Location:http://www.bing.com/search?q=".$_GET["q"]);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fake search</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="fakeSearch.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="q" value=""/><br/>
Google <input type="radio" name="engine" value="google"/><br/>
Yahoo <input type="radio" name="engine" value="yahoo"/><br/>
Bing <input type="radio" name="engine" value="bing"/><br/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

but when i made a login page and redirected to home.php which has the same code as above with session variable it gives me error
    Object not found!

```
 The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error. 

 If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. 
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
```

this is the code

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["authenticated"]))
{
if($_SESSION["authenticated"]==TRUE)
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Home</title></head>
<body>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<?php
if(isset($_GET["engine"]))
{
if($_GET["engine"]=="google")
header("Location:http://www.google.com/search?q=".$_GET["q"]);
elseif($_GET["engine"]=="yahoo")
header("Location:http://search.yahoo.com/search?q=".$_GET["q"]);
if($_GET["engine"]=="bing")
header("Location:http://www.bing.com/search?q=".$_GET["q"]);
}
?>
<form action="fakeSearch.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="q" value=""/><br/>
Google <input type="radio" name="engine" value="google"/><br/>
Yahoo <input type="radio" name="engine" value="yahoo"/><br/>
Bing <input type="radio" name="engine" value="bing"/><br/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php }
else{
header("Location:login.php.");
}?>
```

Comment: `if($_SESSION["authenticated"]==TRUE)` is missing the curly braces

Comment: maybe that line can be nixed and the first test should be `if(isset($_SESSION["authenticated"]) && $_SESSION["authenticated"] == TRUE)`

Comment: I didn't miss the curly brace.IT is there in the end.I wanted the HTML code to execute only if that condition holds true.And i would have got a syntax error if i made that mistake which i don't.

Comment: does login.php exist in the same path as home.php or should the redirect  be `Location: /login.php` instead

Comment: It exists in the same directory

Comment: 404 indicates file not found... are you sure you are looking in the right place?  try putting a `<?php die("You are at the right place"); ?>` at the very top of the file to make sure there isn't any goofy rewrite business happening.

Comment: Is it working fine now bhushanpatil?

Comment: Nope.It is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form action you are using fakesearch.php

```
<form action="fakeSearch.php" method="GET">
```

But you are writing action coding with in the same file

```
if(isset($_GET["engine"]))
{
if($_GET["engine"]=="google")
header("Location:http://www.google.com/search?q=".$_GET["q"]);
elseif($_GET["engine"]=="yahoo")
header("Location:http://search.yahoo.com/search?q=".$_GET["q"]);
if($_GET["engine"]=="bing")
header("Location:http://www.bing.com/search?q=".$_GET["q"]);
}
```

after clicking submit button, it will search to find the fakesearch.php file

Try to use "#" or make an empty in the action attribute in the form tag.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["authenticated"]))
{
if($_SESSION["authenticated"]==TRUE)
?>
```

Try to put this code after the body tag

```
  if($_SESSION["authenticated"]==TRUE)  {
```

I think, open curly brace is missing.(Idea from @ Orangepil)

All the best!

Comment: this files name is fakeSearch.php

Comment: It's PHP and not JS that it'll be processed there only.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the trailing period after "php" in "Location:login.php."

Comment: Thanks for correcting that
But it still doesn't fix my problem
When i post the correct username and password that condition won't even execute so that can't really create problem

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra period at the end of your redirect. Try this instead:

```
header("Location:login.php");
```